# render the show page, inside my index page through a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, partial-views

I am using a Modal to pop up the show page inside the index page.....Everything works just fine until I start using @product.name in my show page partial.

I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I know it's an easy fix, please help....new to rails 
This is my code:

**Views**

_show.html.erb

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="content-inner hero-unit">
    <h1 class="pump-up center">
      <br>
      <strong>Coming Soon.</strong></h1>
      <br><br>
      <p>
        <b>Name: </b>
        **<%= @product.name %>**
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "show", :locals => { :product => @product }  %>

<div class="row">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="span3">

        <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
        <%=(image_tag product.photo(:medium))%></a>

      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Model**

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :photo
end
```

**Controller**

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end


  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

end
```

Comment: Hello Surge how did you solve the "same product name on different products problem"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering the `index` template with the `index` action so `@product` in your scope is `Nil`. You have to call the render partial inside the loop with each product.

`index.html.erb` should be something like that:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="span3">
        <%= render :partial => "show", :locals => { :product => product }  %>
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
        <%=(image_tag product.photo(:medium))%></a>

      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You are also using incorrectly the variable in the partial. When you pass a local variable and you reference it, you should call with `product` in your case.

Comment: Okay, now for some reason.....when the modal pops up. it uses the same product name on different products....(should i post another question)..@Pigueiras

Comment: I can't take a look now at the documentation but the reason probably is that all the modals have the same id, i think that you should put a different id for each product modal

Answer (score 2):

For anyone lazy roaming around for solution like me:

*index.html.erb* should be something like that:

```
<div class="row">
 <% @products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
  <div class="span3">
    <%= render :partial => "show", :locals => { :product => product, :index => index }  %>
    <a href=<%="#myModal_#{index}"%> role="button" data-toggle="modal">
    <%=(image_tag product.photo(:medium))%></a>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

*show.html.erb* should be something like that:

```
<div id=<%="myModal_#{index}"%> class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"   aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="content-inner hero-unit">
 <h1 class="pump-up center">
  <br>
  <strong>Coming Soon.</strong></h1>
  <br><br>
  <p>
    <b>Name: </b>
    **<%= product.name %>**
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```